# TDD of has_many through Model validations with RSpec & Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, has-many-through

Consider the following:

```
ScheduledSession ------> Applicant <------ ApplicantSignup
```

Points to note:

1. A ScheduledSession will exist in the system at all times; think of this as a class or course.
2. The intent here is to validate the ApplicantSignup model against an attribute on ScheduledSession during `signups_controller#create`

**Associations**

```
class ScheduledSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applicants, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :applicant_signups, :through => :applicants
  #...
end

class ApplicantSignup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applicants, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :scheduled_sessions, :through => :applicants
  #...
end

class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scheduled_session
  belongs_to :applicant_signup

  # TODO: enforce validations for presence
  # and uniqueness constraints etc.
  #...
end
```

**SignupsController**

Resources are RESTful, i.e. the `#create` action will have a path that's similar to `/scheduled_sessions/:id/signups/new`

```
def new
  @session = ScheduledSession.find(params[:scheduled_session_id])
  @signup = @session.signups.new
end

def create
  @session = ScheduledSession.find(params[:scheduled_session_id])
  @session.duration = (@session.end.to_time - @session.start.to_time).to_i
  @signup = ApplicantSignup.new(params[:signup].merge(:sessions => [@session]))

  if @signup.save
   # ...
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

You'll notice I'm setting a virtual attribute above `@session.duration` to prevent Session from being considered invalid.  The real 'magic' if you will happens in `@signup = ApplicantSignup.new(params[:signup].merge(:sessions => [@session]))` which now means that in the model I can select from `self.scheduled_sessions` and access the ScheduledSession this ApplicantSignup is being built against, even though *at this very point in time, there is no record present in the join table*.

Model validations for example look like

```
def ensure_session_is_upcoming
  errors[:base] << "Cannot signup for an expired session" unless self.scheduled_sessions.select { |r| r.upcoming? }.size > 0
end

def ensure_published_session
  errors[:base] << "Cannot signup for an unpublished session" if self.scheduled_sessions.any? { |r| r.published == false }
end

def validate_allowed_age
  # raise StandardError, self.scheduled_sessions.inspect
  if self.scheduled_sessions.select { |r| r.allowed_age == "adults" }.size > 0
    errors.add(:dob_year) unless (dob_year.to_i >= Time.now.strftime('%Y').to_i-85 && dob_year.to_i <= Time.now.strftime('%Y').to_i-18)
    # elsif ... == "children"
  end
end
```

The above works quite well in `development` and the validations work as expected — but how does one test with with Factory Girl?  I want unit tests to guarantee the business logic I've implemented after all — sure, this is after the fact but is still one way of going about TDD.

You'll notice I've got a commented out `raise StandardError, self.scheduled_sessions.inspect` in the last validation above — this returns `[]` for `self.scheduled_sessions` which indicates that my Factory setup is just not right.

**One of Many Attempts =)**

```
it "should be able to signup to a session" do
  scheduled_session = Factory.build(:scheduled_session)
  applicant_signup = Factory.build(:applicant_signup)
  applicant = Factory.create(:applicant, :scheduled_session => scheduled_session, :applicant_signup => applicant_signup)
  applicant_signup.should be_valid
end

it "should be able to signup to a session for adults if between 18 and 85 years" do
  scheduled_session = Factory.build(:scheduled_session)
  applicant_signup = Factory.build(:applicant_signup)
  applicant_signup.dob_year = 1983 # 28-years old
  applicant = Factory.create(:applicant, :scheduled_session => scheduled_session, :applicant_signup => applicant_signup)
  applicant_signup.should have(0).error_on(:dob_year)
end
```

The first one passes, but I honestly do not believe it's properly validating the applicant_signup model; the fact that `self.scheduled_sessions` is returning `[]` simply means that the above just isn't right.

It's quite possible that I'm trying to test something outside the scope of Factory Girl, or is there a far better approach to tackling this?  Appreciate all comments, advice and constructive criticism!

*Updates:*

- Not sure what this is called but this is the approach taken at least with regards to [how it's implemented at the controller level](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=20203)
- I need to consider ignoring Factory Girl for the association aspect at least and attempt to return the `scheduled_session` by mocking `scheduled_sessions` on the `applicant_signup` model.

*Factories*

```
FactoryGirl.define do  
  factory :signup do
    title "Mr."
    first_name "Franklin"
    middle_name "Delano"
    last_name "Roosevelt"
    sequence(:civil_id) {"#{'%012d' %  Random.new.rand((10 ** 11)...(10 ** 12))}"}    
    sequence(:email) {|n| "person#{n}@#{(1..100).to_a.sample}example.com" }
    gender "male"
    dob_year "1980"
    sequence(:phone_number) { |n| "#{'%08d' %  Random.new.rand((10 ** 7)...(10 ** 8))}" }
    address_line1 "some road"
    address_line2 "near a pile of sand"
    occupation "code ninja"
    work_place "Dharma Initiative"
  end

  factory :session do
    title "Example title"
    start DateTime.civil_from_format(:local,2011,12,27,16,0,0)
    duration 90
    language "Arabic"
    slides_language "Arabic & English"
    venue "Main Room"
    audience "Diabetic Adults"
    allowed_age "adults"
    allowed_gender "both"
    capacity 15
    published true
    after_build do |session|
      # signups will be assigned manually on a per test basis
      # session.signups << FactoryGirl.build(:signup, :session => session)
    end  
  end

  factory :applicant do
    association :session
    association :signup
  end

  #...
end
```

Comment: You should provide information on your factories for Models. If none present, try to create one that uses `after_build` callback or `association` type of declaration. As another approach you could use Rspecs `stub_model`. Also, if you test `ApplicantSignup`, you should init it and dont test the creation of the `Applicant`. For example: `applicant_signup = Factory.build(:applicant_signup);
applicant_signup.should_receive(:scheduled_sessions).and_return{[scheduled_session]};`. So there will be less DB access, and you will test `ApplicantSignup`, not `Applicant`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, please see my update as requested.  Will fully digest your comment later this evening!  I was having the above issues with the `association` declaration as seen above.  I stopped using the `after_build` callback in favour of setting things up in the test itself.  Ha! `applicant_signup.should_receive(:scheduled_sessions).and_return{[scheduled_sessi‌​on]};` - should do the trick, exactly similar to the idea of stubbing `:scheduled_sessions` out and returning an array - that should work!

Comment: Interestingly I'm getting `(#<ApplicantSignup:0x00000100ee5e20>).scheduled_sessions(any args)` -- `expected: 1 time; received: 10 times`.  The good news is this works though: `StandardError:
       [#<ScheduledSession id: nil, title: "Example title", start: "2011-12-27 13:00:00", end: nil, language: "Arabic", audience: "Diabetic Adults", allowed_gender: "both", capacity: 15, version: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, allowed_age: "adults", published: true, slides_language: "Arabic & English", venue: "Main Room">]`

Comment: Success! `stub!(..)` works, which was my untested idea above.  Thanks so much Mark!  Post your comment as an answer and the bounty is yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My earlier assumption was correct, with on small change:

> I need to consider ignoring Factory Girl for the association aspect at
>   least and attempt to return the scheduled_session by ***stubbing***
>   scheduled_sessions on the applicant_signup model.

making my tests quite simply:

```
it "should be able to applicant_signup to a scheduled_session" do
  scheduled_session = Factory(:scheduled_session)
  applicant_signup = Factory.build(:applicant_signup)
  applicant_signup.stub!(:scheduled_sessions).and_return{[scheduled_session]}
  applicant_signup.should be_valid
end

it "should be able to applicant_signup to a scheduled_session for adults if between 18 and 85 years" do
  scheduled_session = Factory(:scheduled_session)
  applicant_signup = Factory.build(:applicant_signup)
  applicant_signup.dob_year = 1983 # 28-years old
  applicant_signup.stub!(:scheduled_sessions).and_return{[scheduled_session]}
  applicant_signup.should have(0).error_on(:dob_year)
  applicant_signup.should be_valid
end
```

and this test in particular required a similar approach:

```
it "should not be able to applicant_signup if the scheduled_session capacity has been met" do
  scheduled_session = Factory.build(:scheduled_session, :capacity => 3)
  scheduled_session.stub_chain(:applicant_signups, :count).and_return(3)    
  applicant_signup = Factory.build(:applicant_signup)
  applicant_signup.stub!(:scheduled_sessions).and_return{[scheduled_session]}
  applicant_signup.should_not be_valid
end
```

...and success — ignore the testing duration as `spork` causes false reporting of this.

```
Finished in 2253.64 seconds
32 examples, 0 failures, 3 pending
Done.
```

Comment: You should feel the difference between `stub` and `should_receive` as latter is more useful as it also fails if the method wasn't called or if it was called wrong number of times:
`<some_obj>.should_receive(:method).once.and_return(<value>)`. Notice `once` specified. Also on that place could be 'never', so it will test that `:method` **not** called.

Comment: Off topic, but, 2253 seconds on 32 specs? I advice to refactor your specs to be more robust.

Comment: Mark, _ignore the testing duration as spork causes false reporting of this._.

Comment: Mark, stub and should_receive fulfil different purposes. A should_receive is an explicit expectation that marks the method call as an essential part of the behaviour you are currently exploring. A stub marks out the method as not mattering.

Comment: @workmad3 I agree, but in this case specs check the behavior of the validation, and from that point we could expect that `scheduled_sessions` should be called.

Comment: @MarkGuk that's true but I don't believe the number of times the method call is being made matters considering that the count represents calls from across all the validations; `at_least(1)` therefore could easily come from a different validation. `Also you can check the required count of call from your code and write this number as expectation` Sure, but this would also require updating the count each time `scheduled_sessions` is called on the instantiated class instance (object).  `stub!` therefore makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

As another approach you could use Rspecs `stub_model`.

Also, if you test `ApplicantSignup`, you should init it and not test the creation of the `Applicant`. Eg:

```
applicant_signup = Factory.build(:applicant_signup);

applicant_signup.should_receive(:scheduled_sessions)
                           .and_return{[scheduled_sessi‌​on]};
```

So there will be less DB access and you will test ApplicantSignup, not Applicant.

Comment: `should_receive` causes a failure as it gets called 10 times, instead of once.  It's the reason I just went with stub; any thoughts?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, as you wrote several validations methods that call `scheduled_sessions`. As in your question I have spotted 3 calls. So I propose for you to use `stub!` or user `at_least(1)` after `should_validate` to allow any times of calls, but require the one call. Also you can check the required count of call from your code and write this number as expectation.

Comment: I've got a lot more validations, that's why each one is being counted.  That makes complete sense - validation triggers *all* the validations, not _just the one I'm testing_!